# Is it possible to use a conditional statement in an Idiom Bracket in Idris?

Tags: syntactic-sugar, applicative, idris

An expression like the following is perfectly valid in Idris:

```
 let x = Just 5 in let y = Just 6 in [|x / y|]
```

Could someone write an expression like the following?

```
let x = Just 5 in let y = Just 6 in [| if x == 0 then 0 else y|]
```

I can't seem to get it to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this working by taking care of two problems:

1. `if _ then _ else _` doesn't seem to propagate the idiom bracket to its subexpressions
2. The default definition of `if _ then _ else _` is (of course) lazy in its two branches, and `Lazy' LazyEval` doesn't seem to lift instances.

Once these two were worked around, I was able to get it working in an idiom bracket. Note however that this wouldn't work for an applicative where taking both branches has an observable effect.

```
strictIf : Bool -> a -> a -> a
strictIf True t e = t
strictIf False t e = e

syntax "if" [b] "then" [t] "else" [e] = strictIf b t e

test : Maybe Float
test = let x = Just 5 
           y = Just 6
       in [| if [| x == pure 0 |] then [|0|] else y |]
```

Comment: Oh gosh! It took me a while to figure out how this actually worked. That last expression looked like it should not compile at first but I think I understand how it works now.

Comment: I will take that as a "not really". Because I don't think Idiom Brackets are worth it at this point. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!